# How to Display JSON Data in html using Angular 7?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api, angular7

I am getting below JSON Response from OpenWeatherMap API. I Want to Display the CityName, CityCode, Temperature & Description in a HTML Table.

JSON Response :

```
cnt : 1
list
0
coord
  lon : 79.85
  lat : 6.93
sys
  type : 1
  id : 9098
  message : 0.0032
  country : "LK"
  sunrise : 1554597365
  sunset : 1554641358
weather
  0
main
  temp : 30
  pressure : 1010
  humidity : 70
  temp_min : 30
  temp_max : 30
visibility : 10000
wind
  speed : 2.6
  deg : 200
clouds
  all : 20
dt : 1554655382
id : 1248991
name : "Colombo"
```

HTML File :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>City Code</th>
            <th>Temperature</th>
            <th>Description</th>            
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{{weather.list.name}}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>              
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Weather.Service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {

  apiKey = '9402da6bd74c395f71604c624cc2b231';
  url;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
    this.url='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=';  //API GET URL

  }

  getWeather(cityCode){
    return this.http.get(this.url+cityCode+'&units=metric&appid='+this.apiKey);
  }

}
```

Home.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from "../shared/weather.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  location={    
    code: '1248991'
  };

  public weather: any;

  constructor(private weatherService:WeatherService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherService.getWeather(this.location.code).subscribe((Response)=>{
      console.log(Response);
      this.weather = Response;
    })
  }

}
```

This is the Error that i am getting in Console

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
>           at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (HomeComponent.html:30)

Comment: Try weather?.list.name using elvis operator

Comment: It takes time to fetch the data, so for a moment weather is undefined and underined.list throws an error

Comment: Tried both still no output

Comment: Could you paste the json ersponse?

Comment: Not like that open developer tools in the chrome then select network tab and then refresh your page. click on the weather request in the network tab, then click on the 'response' tab and paste response here

Comment: Try displaynig id instead of the list

Comment: In your html have an *ngIf condition.                                                                     <tr *ngIf="weather" >  <td>{{weather.list.name}}</td></tr>                                             to check if you have weather fetched

Comment: @MishoTek Here I passed the City Code in a Static Way. But Actually i have to read the CityCodes from another JSON file and send for the API Request. How can i do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i remember , openweathermap api returns list and results as  an array, its not an Object. You need to access list property from the response.

Here is a sample response,

> {"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light
>   intensity
>   drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

Also use safe navigation operator **`?`** to handle if there is an empty result on the list.

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-live-search-switchmap-fbrhft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: The Demo Works..! Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It takes time to load data from the server, so for a moment, your weather is undefined and undefined.list throws an error. So You have two options: to use elvis operator in your html `weather?.list.name` it lets you safely access weather
or use `<table *ngIf="weather" class="table table-hover">` to check if you have weather fetched. Also, make sure that there is `.name` attribute and that you don't have to iterate with `*ngFor`

Answer (score 1):

When i have this problems, i do:
{{ weather | json }} in html and see tree.